# CSS FLEXBOX: How to align last item to the left in a justify-content:space-between grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with styles as follows:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

And every child of that div has:

```
flex: 0 1 32%;
```

And if I have three child divs it looks as follows:

[image]

And that is fine. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2sc7amL1/1/

But the problem is when I have only child elements, then I have something as follows

[image]

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2sc7amL1/2/

How can I do that with flex if I have only two child divs that the are left aligned as on the photo

[image]

Comment: justify-content: flex-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `:last-child` is also the `:nth-child(2)`. In that case change the margin of the element

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: yellow;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 1 32%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.parent > div:last-child:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 auto 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>


<br /> <br />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I'm going to accept the answer in 3 minutes. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Add justify-content: flex-start to the parent classname.If you need spaces between the children divs, add margin to the child elements.

```
.parent{
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.child:nth-child(even){
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

here's the edited of your https://jsfiddle.net/v8wnruxc/1/

Comment: Thanks, but in this case if I have three child divs, the last one has also a margin-right.

Comment: margin: 0 20px; second child div (all even child divs) will work, i edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `justify-content: flex-start` like the other answers. The technique you want might be:

```
.parent::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 32%;
}
```

Try the code below, with 2 and 3 children respectively. Source of the technique: https://haizdesign.com/css/flexbox-align-last-item-grid-left/

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 32%;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 1 32%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> Child </div>
  <div class="child"> Child </div>
  <div class="child"> Child </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> Child </div>
  <div class="child"> Child </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also gives the right result, but @fcalderan was a little faster, thus I must accept his answer and upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like that?

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;;
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 1 32%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(3n) {   flex-grow: 1;} /* fix as for comment */
```

here snippet:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;;
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 1 32%;
  margin: 0 0.5%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(3n) {   flex-grow: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>      
  
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Child 4
  </div>
    
  <div class="child">
    Child 5
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    Child 6
  </div>
</div>
```

[This link](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) is helpful in order to get all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case if I have three child divs, the last one has also a margin-right.

Comment: You can fix it with `.child:nth-child(3n) {   flex-grow: 1;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent > div:last-child:nth-child(2) {
  margin:0 auto 0 30px;
 }
```

you can use `nth-child` also